# make new column based on presence of a word in another

Tags: pandas, dataframe, substring

I have

```
pd.DataFrame({'text':['fewfwePDFerglergl','htrZIPg','gemlHTML']})
    text
0   wePDFerglergl
1   htrZIPg
2   gemlHTML
```

a column 10k rows long. Each column contains one of ['PDF','ZIP','HTML']. The length of each entry in text is 14char max.

how do I get:

```
pd.DataFrame({'text':['wePDFerglergl','htrZIPg','gemlHTML'],'file_type':['pdf','zip','html']})
    text            file_type
0   wePDFerglergl   pdf
1   htrZIPg         zip
2   gemlHTML        html
```

I tried `df.text[0].find('ZIP')` for a single entry, but do not know how to stitch it all together to test and return the correct value for each row in the column

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) here with the regex flag for in-case sensitive `(?i)`

```
words =  ['pdf','zip','html']
df['file_type'] = df['text'].str.extract(f'(?i)({"|".join(words)})')
```

Or we use the `flags=re.IGNORECASE` argument:

```
import re
df['file_type'] = df['text'].str.extract(f'({"|".join(words)})', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

**Output**

```
                text file_type
0  fewfwePDFerglergl       PDF
1            htrZIPg       ZIP
2           gemlHTML      HTML
```

---

If you want `file_type` as lower case, chain [`str.lower()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.lower.html):

```
df['file_type'] = df['text'].str.extract(f'(?i)({"|".join(words)})')[0].str.lower()
```

```
                text file_type
0  fewfwePDFerglergl       pdf
1            htrZIPg       zip
2           gemlHTML      html
```

**Details**:
The pipe (`|`) is the `or` operator in regular expressions. So with:

```
"|".join(words)

'pdf|zip|html'
```

We get the following in pseudocode:

> extract "pdf" or "zip" or "html" from our string

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex for this:

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r'(PDF|ZIP|HTML)')
```

This matches any of the desired substrings. To extract these matches in order in proper case, here's a one-liner:

```
file_type = [re.search(regex, x).group().lower() for x in df['text']]
```

This returns the following list:

```
['pdf', 'zip', 'html']
```

Then to add the column:

```
df['file_type'] = file_type
```